# Excel autofills the formulas correctly but the values remain the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my excel sheet, I tried the simple autofill and it was working fine. Then today, it started copying the same values in all columns instead of updating the values. The formulas inside are different and what they should be, but the values are the same as the first one. For example if a column has formula "=B1/A1" and the value 23.5, then the autofill fills the formulas as "=B2/A2" and so on but the value is still 23.5 for all columns. When I go to each cell individually and press enter on the formula, only then it updates. I've been googling for an hpur, but can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: Ok, it was automatic calculation. WTH Excel changes stuff randomly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on your automatic calculation, so that the formulas are automatically calculated.

### press `F9` to:

> Recalculate formulas that have changed since the last calculation, and
>   formulas dependent on them, in all open workbooks. If a workbook is
>   set for automatic recalculation, you do not need to press F9 for
>   recalculation.

### `SHIFT+F9`

> Recalculate formulas that have changed since the last calculation, and
>   formulas dependent on them, in the active worksheet.

### `CTRL+ALT+F9`

> Recalculate all formulas in all open workbooks, regardless of whether
>   they have changed since last time or not.

### `CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+F9`

> Recheck dependent formulas, and then recalculate all formulas in all
>   open workbooks, regardless of whether they have changed since last
>   time or not.

**or just simply go to `Options`>`Formulas`>`Calculation options`> turn on `Automatic` workbook calculation.**